# Looking for proper way to use ajax to post an MVC 5 View to a controller

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have an MVC 5 app which I am trying to use ajax to perform a post to avoid the page from doing a full reload after a post. The web page is basically a Contact page. I am using Visual Studio 2017 for this web app. I am also using the Nuget package for CaptchaMVC.MVC5. The MVC 5 Application has the following problems:

I am unable to read the value from the Message TextArea web element in the javascript I have.

The json object I create in the ajax code is reaching the ContactController and entering the ContactCreate action method but the values from the java script in the view are not coming across. They are all null.

I am trying to send the ajax success and error results to a  element but it is not happening. I am not sure how to do this in the ajax call.

I would appreciate any suggest to fix the listed problems. Thanks in advance.

Here is the Contact Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace rgmsite.Models
{
  public class Contact
  {
    [Required(ErrorMessage="The name of the person submitting this form is required")]
    [DisplayName("Your Name")]
    [StringLength(128, MinimumLength = 2)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The email address to reply back to is required")]
    [StringLength(128, MinimumLength = 5)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The subject of this contact request is required")]
    [StringLength(128, MinimumLength = 2)]
    public string Subject { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "A message describing why you are submitting a contact request is required")]
    [StringLength(250, ErrorMessage = "The number of characters allowed for a message is 5 to 250", MinimumLength=5)]
    public string Message { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Here is the Contact Controller:

```
using rgmsite.Models;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using CaptchaMvc.HtmlHelpers;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace rgmsite.Controllers
{
  public class ContactController : Controller
  {
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ContactNew()
    {
      return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ContactCreate(Contact aContact)
    {
      if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {
        // Code for validating the CAPTCHA  
        if (this.IsCaptchaValid("Captcha is not valid"))
        {
          return RedirectToAction("ThankYouPage", aContact);
        }
      }

        ViewBag.ErrMessage = "Error: captcha is not valid.";

      return View("ContactNew", null, aContact);
    }

    public ActionResult ThankYouPage(Contact aContact)
    {
      return View(aContact);
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the ContactNew View:

```
@model rgmsite.Models.Contact
@using CaptchaMvc.HtmlHelpers;
@using CaptchaMvc;


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<!--
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
-->

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ContactCreate",
                        "Contact",
                        null,
                        new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "UpdateArea1" },
                        new { id = "ContactFormId" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset id="ContactForm">
        <legend>Contact</legend>

        <div id="UpdateArea1">
            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

            <div class="form-group row">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-4 col-sm-3 col-md-4 col-lg-2 col-xl-2" })
                <div class="col-8 col-sm-9 col-md-8 col-lg-10 col-xl-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "NameId" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-4 col-sm-3 col-md-4 col-lg-2 col-xl-2" })
                <div class="col-8 col-sm-9 col-md-8 col-lg-10 col-xl-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "EmailId" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Subject, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-4 col-sm-3 col-md-4 col-lg-2 col-xl-2" })
                <div class="col-8 col-sm-9 col-md-8 col-lg-10 col-xl-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Subject, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "SubjectId" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Subject, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Message, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-4 col-sm-3 col-md-4 col-lg-2 col-xl-2" })
                <div class="col-8 col-sm-9 col-md-8 col-lg-10 col-xl-10">
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Message, 4, 40, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "MessageId" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Message, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row" >
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div >
                        <p class="Error">
                            @ViewBag.ErrMessage<br />
                        </p>
                        <div id="PostResults">
                            Results go here.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <p>
                @Html.MathCaptcha()
            </p>
            <br />

        </div>
    </fieldset>


    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="button" id="PostButton" value="Send Contact Info" />
    </div>


}
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#PostButton").click(function () {
            var Contact = {};
            Contact.Name    = $("#NameId").val();
            Contact.Email   = $("#EmailId").val();
            Contact.Subject = $("#SubjectId").val();
            Contact.Message = $("#MessageId").val();
            $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Contact/ContactCreate",
                    data: '{Contact: ' + JSON.stringify(Contact) + '}',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    datatype: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        var result = $('<div />').append(data).find('#PostResults').html();
                        $('PostResults').html(result);
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        var result = $('<div />').append(data).find('#PostResults').html();
                        $('PostResults').html(result);
                    },

                });
        });
    });

</script>



@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

}
```

Here is the ThankYou View:

```
@model rgmsite.Models.Contact

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Thank You";

      Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

}
<p>
    <h2>Thank You</h2>
</p>
<div>
    <h4>Summary of Contact Information Received</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Email)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Subject)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Subject)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Message)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Message)
        </dd>

    </dl>
</div>
```

Comment: There are multiple error with your code. But why do you have `return RedirectToAction(...)` in your controller method - ajax calls cannot redirect (the whole point of ajax is to stay on the same page) so its not clear what you are trying to do

Comment: I'd like to just delete this post but got a message I would be suspended  if i did so just ignore this post. For me it was just simpler to do it all in mvc and C# with no javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript has plenty of errors. I don't see how you define the model in js. your action return HTML, but you define contentType json. For serializing in javascript, you should use JSON.stringify

Comment: I am going to redo the question and code. What would ultimately help is if I could find a complete example (not a snippet here and there like I see all over the net) showing how to make an MVC 5 Form to post data from a view to the controller without causing a whole page refresh. I think this is done with Ajax but I don't have a working example to follow. I tried to do this with strongly typed view based on an MVC model called Contact which is passed into the view and referenced with the word "model". A URL to a complete example would be good.